# How to cast keyof exports to string type

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have this:

```
export const USER_SETTINGS_UPDATED = 'c_USER_SETTINGS_UPDATED';
export const GET_USER = 'c_GET_USER';
export const EMAIL_RECORDS_RECEIVED = 'c_EMAIL_RECORDS_RECEIVED';

export type UserConstants = keyof typeof exports;
```

the problem is that `UserConstants` is not a string, but instead `string | number | symbol`...is there a way to cast `UserConstants` to a string type, or better yet, get the values instead of the keys?

GOAL: I am looking for a type that looks like:

```
type UserConstants = 'c_USER_SETTINGS_UPDATED' | 'c_GET_USER' | 'c_EMAIL_RECORDS_RECEIVED'
```

I tried this:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
export type UserConstants = ValueOf<typeof exports>;
```

but that simply yields:

```
type UserConstants = string
```

Comment: Are you look looking for a TS equivalent of an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by dynamically importing the source file with `import()`.

For example: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wKoGUCiAlAfVwBViBJAOQHEsCMAFAEQEFidG4BeOAcgTtyES5arQYs2jHgG4AsAChQkWIhTo4VHMQH4uvfpu3Z8MhUujwkaeDgCyzMgBkCeHAGEA8nka1XbnGQAaux6fAR2Ds5+Xj4u7gHBUnLyZuAWcDAAnmDAcBiowFBuajAAhsgwqHpZORAAZnAAlgC2yjAAFDwAdAD0jchgAK4wPACUANoA1sCZ9RnZwHMtbZ29-UMjowC60kA)

```
export const USER_SETTINGS_UPDATED = 'c_USER_SETTINGS_UPDATED';
export const GET_USER = 'c_GET_USER';
export const EMAIL_RECORDS_RECEIVED = 'c_EMAIL_RECORDS_RECEIVED';

export type UserConstants = typeof import('./input')[keyof typeof import('./input')];
```

You do not need an extra object as Chris implies.

Comment: Clever! I like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof exports` is `any`, so `keyof typeof exports` is `symbol | string | symbol`.

You could declare an object with your constants, export it as the default, and additionally export the type. That should get you what you want. Each individual constant is importable, as is the `UserConstants` type.

```js
const constants = {
  USER_SETTINGS_UPDATED: 'c_USER_SETTINGS_UPDATED',
  GET_USER: 'c_GET_USER',
  EMAIL_RECORDS_RECEIVED: 'c_EMAIL_RECORDS_RECEIVED',
}

export type UserConstants = keyof typeof constants;
export default constants;
```

Comment: You have changed the shape of his exports  by exporting under default. This isn't necessary and is a rather ugly solution, especially since many people advise against default exports.

Comment: that's ok to change shape of exports, but yeah not sure if this works yet, testing it